# ODE $\ x(y+4)+\frac{dy}{dx}=0 $, with conditions leading to a log of negative number?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Trivial ODE and trivial question:

$$\ x(y+4)+\frac{dy}{dx}=0 $$ with initial conditions $y=-5, x=0$

After we separate variables we get:
$$\ -\frac{dy}{y+4}=x\,dx $$

Integrate left and write parts:

$$-\ln(y+4)=\frac{1}{2}x^2 + C $$

Here we see that if $y=-5 $ we have a log of negative number. 
Trying not to think about it, I proceed as follows:

Exponentiation of both parts:

$$y = e^{-1/2x^2-C}  - 4$$ 
And then:
$$y = e^{-1/2x^2}e^{-C} - 4$$ 
$$y = e^{-1/2x^2}C - 4$$ 
(this new $C $ to $e^{-C}$ and cannot be negative)
$$-5 = e^{0}C - 4$$
$$C=-1$$
(but we see that it is in fact negative under given initial conditions)

which gives us the correct answer:

$$y = -e^{-1/2x^2} - 4$$

Now I feel that I've cheated somewhere. My only guess that I was able to deal with a log of a negative number and get negative $C $ (which shouldn't be negative) is because I have involved complex numbers between the lines. Is it so? If not, how can I make this solution rigorous?

Thanks!

Comment: Re your first integration, remember that $\int \frac{f'(y)}{f(y)} dy$ on the left, is $\ln(|f(y)| + C$.  So in your case, the LHS should result in $-\ln(|y+4|)$.  Hence ...

Comment: @amWhy Thanks, I totally forgot about it. Then $\ |y+4| = e^{-1/2x^2-C} $. Should I get rid of abs value by considering $\ y<-4 $ and $\ y \ge-4 $ next ?

Comment: That would be a good idea!

Comment: @amWhy So if $\ y<-4 $: $\ -y-4=e^{-1/2x^2-C} $ and $\ y= -e^{-1/2x^2-C} - 4$, then $\ -5 = -e^{-C} - 4 $ and hence $\ C=0 $ which gives the correct answer. Now if if $\ y \ge -4 $:  $\ y+4=e^{-1/2x^2-C} $ and and $\ y= e^{-1/2x^2-C} - 4$ then $\ -5= e^{-C} - 4$ which has no real solutions for $\ C $, right?

Comment: @amWhy btw, feel free to post your first comment as an answer and I will accept it, thanks!

Comment: Sure, @type2, I've posted my comment as an answer.  Glad to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Re: your first integration: remember that $$\int \frac{f'(y)}{f(y)}dy = \ln(|f(y)|) + C$$

So in your case, the LHS should result in $−\ln(|y+4|).$ Hence ...